# Where Mongol herds graze

Tags: knowledge, rhyme, language, geography

> One of us – largest outside polar regions;
>   another one's island's shared with Indonesians;
>   a third one is found at the edge of the first,
>   a break from the dryness to quench people's thirst.
>
> One of us separates Swedes from the Finns;
>   one – lake with skiing, casinos and inns;
>   one's a dry place near where Mongol herds graze;
>   one flows where born was a writer of plays.

What do we have in common?

Comment: i am going to close this question as duplicate.

Comment: V ernyvmr gung Jvxvcrqvn pynvzf 'obga' orvat Byq Abefr sbe 'onl', ohg gung fbhaqf jebat naq lbh jba'g svaq n qvpgvbanel nterrvat jvgu gung pynvz. Gur bevtva bs gur Thys'f anzr vf pbafvqrerq hapyrne.

Comment: @jarnbjo Thanks for the correction. That is definitely problematic for this puzzle. Probably too late to rewrite the line at this point, though...

Comment: It is better to sip Chai tea when you try and solve this puzzle's enigma.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The poem is about

> geographical places with 'duplicate' names. Thanks @OmegaKrypton, @Evergalo and @AHKieran for some of the answers/hints.

One of us – largest outside polar regions;

> [Sahara desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahara) - 'sahra' means 'desert' in an Arabian dialect. *(found by @AHKieran)*

another one's island's shared with Indonesians;

> [East Timor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Timor) - 'timur' is Malayan for 'east'. *(found by @Evargalo)*

a third one is found at the edge of the first,
a break from the dryness to quench people's thirst.

> [Lake Chad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Chad) - 'chad' means 'large expanse of water' in a local language. It lies on the edge of the Sahara (see first line) and it's freshwater so it's drinkable. *(found by @Evargalo)*

One of us separates Swedes from the Finns;

> [Gulf of Bothnia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_of_Bothnia) - 'botn' is Old Norse for 'gulf'.

one – lake with skiing, casinos and inns;

> [Lake Tahoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Tahoe) - 'tahoe' is Washo for 'the lake'. *(pattern found by @OmegaKrypton)*

one's a dry place near where Mongol herds graze;

> [Gobi desert](https://www.britannica.com/place/Gobi) - 'gobi' is Mongolian for 'waterless place'. *(found by @OmegaKrypton)*

one flows where born was a writer of plays.

> Shakespeare was born in Stratford-upon-[Avon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Avon,_Bristol) - 'afon' is Welsh for 'river'. *(pattern found by @OmegaKrypton)*

Comment: remember to add the oasis from @Evargalo's answer! :) +1ed

Comment: The OP stated (in a now deleted comment) that lines 3+4 were about the same place. This is also reflected by the comma at the end of line 3, instead of a semicolon.

Comment: More examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tautological_place_names)

Answer (score 6):

@Glorfindel has found the answer and explicited the second stanza, here is an explanation for the first one:

*One of us – largest outside polar regions;*

> @AHKieran pointed out in a comment that this must be **Sahara Desert**, where "Sahara" means desert in Arabic.

*Another one's island's shared with Indonesians;*

> Timor Island is shared between Indonesia and **East Timor**. But Timor/Timur also means 'East' in Indonesian. So this matches the tautological name pattern noticed by Glorfindel.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Timor

*a third one is found at the edge of the first,*

> Then this will be **Lake Chad**. From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Chad), *The name Chad is a local word meaning "large expanse of water", in other words, a "lake".*

*a break from the dryness to quench people's thirst.*

> **Al-Ahsa Oasis** in Saudi Arabia is the biggest [oasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Ahsa_Oasis) in the world. In Classical Arabic, 'Ahsa' means the sound of water underground.

Comment: Yup, you've got them all. (No separate item related to line 4, it's just there to clarify #3.)

Answer (score 5):

Partial Answer

One of us separates Swedes from the Finns;

> [Tornio/ Torne River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torne_(river))

one – lake with skiing, casinos and inns;

> Lake Tahoe (thanks @Glorfindel), a lake with the name that means "the lake", literally

one's a dry place near where Mongol herds graze;

> [Gobi Desert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gobi_Desert)

one flows where born was a writer of plays.

> Stratford-upon-Avon, birthplace of Shakespeare (thanks @Glorfindel again), where Avon literally means "river"

Comment: I think you're on the right track, The first one is rot13(Gur Fnunen Qrfreg vf gur ynetrfg qrfreg rkpyhqvat gur cbyne qrfregf, naq Fnunen vf qrevirq sebz Qrfreg va Nenovp)